# Make shell command from child process execute in parent (to lock shell)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a user defined command called `lock`. After executing the command, the system will be locked. If we give only the correct password, then only the command
prompt occurs. Now, I want to execute the `lock` command from the script which is
running in background. If we execute the script `lock` command is executed, But it does not lock the current terminal. It locks only the background bash. It does not executed in current bash. How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. The background process doesn't have any way of controlling the foreground shell. They are separate processes. The same way the background script can't set a variable in the foreground process.

Comment: So, there is no way to execute the command in parent shell from child shell. Is it right? Thanks...

Comment: That's right. They are entirely separate processes as much as any two other processes are.

Comment: My requirement is: If My system reaches 1 minute of idle time, the "lock" command will be executed automatically. So far checking the idle time of system the background process will run. If it reaches 1 minute the background process execute the lock command. This is my requirement.    So, is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Does it **need** to lock or could it kill the shell session instead? I don't know of any way to do the lock idea with the shell directly. Things like GNU screen and tmux support this sort of timeout/lock though. For killing the session you can look at the `TMOUT` bash variable. Also whatever this "lock" command is doesn't sound (offhand) very secure. What is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a command before a command is executed from the command prompt using the DEBUG trap:

```
trap 'command' DEBUG
```

This will execute command before each command. Change you background script to create a flag file of some kind when the system is locked. And make your command check if that file exists. Like this:

```
if [[ -f lockfile ]]
then p=
    while [[ "$p" != secret ]]
    do  echo -n password: 
        read p
    done
    rm -f lockfile
fi
```

I am not saying it is secure.

Another method:

Run two shells. The lower shell loops asking for a password and then runs the upper. The upper shell is a normal shell. The background task kills the upper shell when it wants to lock the terminal, returning control to the lower shell.

Comment: My requirement is: If My system reaches 1 minute of idle time, the "lock" command will be executed automatically. So far checking the idle time of system the background process will run. If it reaches 1 minute the background process execute the lock command. This is my requirement.

Comment: That is a solution, not a requirement. A requirement is something like "I want to lock the terminal after a minute". You can run the lock command in background, but it is never going to work.

Comment: You can run the lock command from the DEBUG trap as I suggested, conditionally on the flag file.

Answer (score -1):

I had some issue today. To solve it I had to source the script.

The solution is simple `source <script>`